# Server Maintenance Page on Google Load Balancer while waiting for SSL to provision

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I'm adding a google load balancer and the ssl will take a while to provision and propagate. Is there a way that I can put up a server maintenance page while waiting for the propagation to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can put up a server maintenance page while waiting for the
> propagation to complete?

No. Until the propagation completes, users cannot get past the load balancer to see your maintenance page.

Note: The HTTP and HTTPS listeners operate independently. This means that if you configure the HTTP listener before configuring the HTTPS listener, in most cases, HTTP traffic will continue to flow to the backends while the HTTPS listener is configured - unless your domain is using HSTS or permanent HTTPS redirects.

Comment: Thanks! My domain is using HTTPS redirects. I've just done the switch and it takes 45+ minutes. How does real world business deal with the downtime? I'm not a server or networking guy, is this a normal behaviour or only pertaining to GCP's and Google Cloud Load Balancer?  It seems that there is no way to have zero downtime when migrating to Google Cloud to use Google Cloud Load Balancer and  Google managed SSL.

Comment: @FlyingPenguin DNS changes can take from hours to days to propagate worldwide. There are various steps to perform in a specific order to minimize downtime. I have written other answers that cover this.